# Android DatePicker how to set listener and selected date to show and set to and from date

Tags: java, android, datepicker

How can I set this datepicker to show two selected dates as you would when selecting a flight for example?

[image]

code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <DatePicker
                android:id="@+id/pickerdate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/info"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CalendarView;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Calendar;

/**
 * Created by hp1 on 21-01-2015.
 */
public class Tab2 extends Fragment {

    DatePicker pickerDate;
    TextView info;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2,container,false);

        info = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.info);
        pickerDate = (DatePicker)v.findViewById(R.id.pickerdate);

        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

        pickerDate.init(
                today.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                today.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view,
                                              int year, int monthOfYear,int dayOfMonth) {
                        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),
                                "onDateChanged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        info.setText(
                                "Year: " + year + "\n" +
                                        "Month of Year: " + monthOfYear + "\n" +
                                        "Day of Month: " + dayOfMonth);

                    }});
        return v;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to select a to and from date so if the date where the from is in the future or is greater than the to date. And this shows on the calendar image as shown above. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key word you are looking for is "Range".
Here a link for an android library that marks that range between dates.

https://github.com/borax12/MaterialDateRangePicker